# Initializing a simple list

Tags: c, list

I have 3 files: `main.c` , `node.c` , `node.h`

in my 'node.h` i have:

```
typedef struct Lista Lista;
```

in my `node.c` i have:

```
#include "node.h"
struct Lista{
        int dado;
        Lista* prox;
};
```

in my `main` I have:

```
#include "node.h"
#include "<stdlib.h>"

main{
   Lista* p;
   return 0;
}
```

The `P` value is:

The first element of my list OR the pointer to the first element of my list? 
As I can access:
`p->dado` (first value of the list) and
`p->prox` (pointer to the second element of my list).

Where is `the pointer that points to the first element of the list`

Comment: [A simple tutorial on singly linked lists](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson15.html).

Comment: This can't possibly compile.

Answer (score 3):

`p` is an uninitialized pointer. Dereferencing it is undefined behavior. Until you allocate memory and point `p` to it, you have no list. Once you do allocate memory and point `p` to it, `p` is a pointer to a list element. Whether it is the first, or remains so, depends on what else you do.

Comment: So if I use `malloc()` to allocate memory for `p`. It will be an allocated pointer that has `p->data ; p->nextElement`. So 'p`would not be my first element of the list ? Or I just use `p->nextElement` to point to another pointer that will be my first element ?

Comment: Generally there is a head variable.

Comment: @FiddlingBits Thats the term, `head variable`. Would my `p`be the head ?

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro Sure, but I'd suggest actually calling it head for readability.

Comment: `p` itself would be a pointer to a list element. "First" or "head" is for you to decide, it has no inherent meaning. If you keep track of `p` and program with it as first in your mind, then it is first. If you allocate a new node and assign the new node's `prox` member as `p`, then your new node would be first or the head.

Comment: So if I want  `p` to  be my `head varaible`. I just use `p->prox` to points to the first element and `p->data` I leave it as `NULL` ? Would that be correct ?

Comment: If you want `p` to be the head, then `p` is pointing to the first element. `p->dado` would contain whatever meaning you want to give your first element. `p->prox`, once assigned, would point to your second element.

Answer (score 2):

`p` is the pointer to first element in your list.  `p->(something)` is used to get the value of variable pointed by it.

Answer (score 1):

As written your code will not compile.

In your header file, you can create your struct as:

```
typedef struct Lista{
    int dado;
    struct Lista *prox;
}LISTA;
```

Then in your .c, use the following lines to create LISTA instantiation and pointer to LISTA:

```
LISTA *pL, l;//create instantiation and pointer to LISTA
pL = &l; //initialize pL to an instantiation of LISTA

pL = malloc(sizeof(LISTA));//assign space to pointer to LISTA
```

After these steps, `pL` points to the start of your struct instantiation, owns memory (space) and provides the reference from which to access values at the member locations:

```
pL->dado;
pL->prox; //also needs to be initialized and given space before use
```

Remember to `free(pL);` when finished using it.